# Авторизация на сайте joyreactor через библиотеку requests

Tags: python, requests, post, get, авторизация

я пытался логиниться и на сайт joyreactor/login
и на их api api.joyreactor.cc/graphql

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import fake_useragent
import json
import lxml
from lxml import html

url = "https://api.joyreactor.cc/graphql"

query = "mutation Login($login: String!, $password: String!){login(name:$login,password:$password) {me {token}}}"

ans = requests.post(url, json={'query': query, 'variables': {'login': 'python_parser', 'password': 'python_parser'}})

print(ans.json())
print(ans.text)
```

но после этого при гет запросе на другие страницы я всё равно был не авторизован

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import fake_useragent
import json
import lxml
from lxml import html

headers = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0"

url = "http://joyreactor.cc/login"

session = requests.Session()

z = session.get(url=url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(z.text,"html5lib")
x = soup.find("form",class_='sfSignin').find_all("input")
#print(x[-2])
l = x[-2].get("value")
print(l)



params_rinat2 = {
    'signin[username]': 'python_parser',
    'signin[password]': 'python_parser',
    'signin[_csrf_token]': l
}

popitka = session.post(url=url,data=params_rinat2)

print(popitka)
print(popitka.headers)
```

тут я пытался получить csrf токен гет запросом и потом на тот же сайт с этим токеном проийти авторизацию но после этого гет запрос на другую страницу в этой же сессии показывал что я все равно не авторизован

всё что я хочу это авторизоваться в сессии и при следующем гет запросе на другую страницу чтобы я был авторизован...

Comment: Попробуйте авторизацию пройти в рамках открытой сессии которую вы будете потом использовать для запросов

Comment: так я не могу авторизоваться в этом проблема

Comment: Тогда попробуйте куки из респонза авторизации заюзать для сессии

Comment: И еще позвольте полюбопытствовать, что дает авторизация в данном случае? Что не может сделать не авторизованный пользователь?

Comment: даёт доступ к контенту (фото)

Comment: так чтобы получить куки нужно авторизоваться же

Comment: Ток что активировал аккаунт ради любопытства, никакой разницы не заметил

Comment: смотря какую категорию смотреть

Comment: Давай, так. Дай ссылку на то, что нельзя скачать без авторизации... Я сделал и активировал акк попробую разобраться

Comment: Я хочу послать пост запрос и чтобы в сессии осталась АВТОРИЗАЦИЯ и дальше уже чтобы мой парсер мог получить из любой категории контент
суть вопроса 
КАК АВторизоваться

Comment: Я это понял. Дай ссылку на пример который не доступен без авторизации

Comment: https://purgatory.reactor.cc/about

Comment: Я залип. Ночером еще поковыряю. Кому будет интересно поковырять логин karpovan пароль XpS32tpz

Comment: Ну что... помогите...

Comment: Увы, но нет... Тоже не получается